JVM creation failed. Launched via PowerShell script
I was creating a Minecraft launcher in C#, but it didn’t work well, so I switched to PowerShell. The script runs fine, but when I execute it, I get an error message: "Failed to create the JVM. Canceling application" or something similar, without any additional context.
Here is my script:
# Define the Minecraft and Fabric versions
$minecraftVersion = "1.21"  # Minecraft version to launch
$fabricVersion = "0.15.11"  # Fabric loader version
$gameDir = "$env:APPDATA\.minecraft"  # Path to the .minecraft directory
$versionDir = "$gameDir\versions\$minecraftVersion-fabric-$fabricVersion"  # Version-specific directory for Fabric
$assetsDir = "$gameDir\assets"  # Path to the assets directory
$librariesDir = "$gameDir\libraries"  # Path to the libraries directory
$kaydenClientVersion = "1.0"

# Main class for Minecraft with Fabric
$mainClass = "net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient"

# Get the total amount of RAM in GB
$totalRAM = [math]::Round((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 0)

# Allocate RAM up to 64GB
$allocatedRAM = [math]::Min($totalRAM / 1.5, 64)

# JVM arguments, including dynamic memory allocation
$jvmArgs = "-Xmx${allocatedRAM}G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M"

# Construct the classpath (all required JARs for Fabric)
$classPath = "$versionDir\$minecraftVersion-fabric-$fabricVersion.jar;$librariesDir\*"

# Minecraft-specific arguments
$mcArgs = "--version $minecraftVersion-fabric-$fabricVersion --gameDir $gameDir --assetsDir $assetsDir --assetIndex $minecraftVersion"

# Combine JVM and Minecraft arguments
$arguments = "$jvmArgs -cp `"$classPath`" $mainClass $mcArgs"

# Start the Minecraft process using javaw from the system PATH
Start-Process -FilePath "javaw" -ArgumentList $arguments -WorkingDirectory $gameDir

Write-Host "Kayden Client $fabricVersion+$kaydenClientVersion is launching..."

If its a Minecraft issue or a file path issue then tell me I'm not familiar with Minecraft folders that much.

can you provide the complete error trace/message?

@usuario As I said strangely it literally had no error context just a pop up error saying jvm creation failed.
